# Distributing array over a scalars: To splash or not to splash?

Tags: ruby

Say I have an array `a` and want to assign its first element to variable `x` and its second element to variable `y`. Ruby offers me (at least) two possibilities:

```
x,y = a
```

or

```
x,y = *a
```

Aside from the fact that I, personally, find the second form (i.e. using an explicit splash operator) more logical, is there any difference between the two? To be more precise, is it possible that in certain situations (maybe depending on the actual content of `a`) these two variants behave different, and there is a reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: While there is no difference between the two I would like to mention that `*` is generally referred to as a splat not a splash

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! Of course you are right. Don't know how the 'splash' slipped in .... perhaps I'm taking a bath too often.

Comment: Are you a [Bobby Darin](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=QSA-yHzkvP8) fan perchance?

Comment: Not exactly, but I get the point :-D

Comment: BTW, `x, y = a` is a shorthand variant of `(x, y) = a` which denotes [array decomposition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition). The documentation doesn't even mention that you can omit the parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To be more precise, is it possible that in certain situations (maybe depending on the actual content of `a`) these two variants behave different, and there is a reason to prefer one over the other?

The difference is subtle. The former attempts to call `to_ary` (implicit conversion), whereas the latter attempts to call `to_a` (explicit conversion due to `*`):

```
a = Object.new

def a.to_ary
  [1, 2, 3]
end

def a.to_a
  [:a, :b, :c]
end

x, y = a
p x: x, y: y
#=> {:x=>1, :y=>2}

x, y = *a
p x: x, y: y
#=> {:x=>:a, :y=>:b}
```

However, if `a` is an array, there's no difference between the two.

Comment: `Array#to_ary` is the only so-named core method. Are you (or anyone else) aware of an application where it has been useful to define a method `to_ary`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland so far I never had to define `to_ary` (or any other implicit conversion method like `to_hash`, `to_str`, `to_int` etc). An application could be an array-like class that's not a subclass of `Array` or maybe a mock in a test.